# How insert alert after some time in Swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch, dispatch-async

My application asks user question and get answer, each question has some constant time (for example 30 seconds) for answering. I want show user alert something like "Last (n) seconds..." and if user will not answer in that time - app should skips question.
Wrote some code, using DispatchQueue:

```
    let timePerQuestion = 20
    let timeStartAlert = 10

    for i in (0..<timeStartAlert) {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: (.now() + .seconds(timePerQuestion-timeStartAlert+i))) {
            self.failureLabel.text = "Left \(Int(timeStartAlert-i)) seconds..."
            self.failureLabel.isHidden = false
        }
    }
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(timePerQuestion)) {
        self.failureLabel.text = "Reseting question"
        self.failureLabel.isHidden = false
        self.quiz.skipQuestion()
        self.playNewRound()
        self.failureLabel.text = "Sorry, that's not it."
    }
```

It works, but those code executes even if user answered question in time.
So how I can "reset" or "clear" DispatchQueue.main for prevent executing this code if user answered in time?

Comment: Just put your conditional, ie. `if !userHasAnswered { ... }`, inside of the block.

Comment: Use a timer instead if gcd, and when user answers the question invalidate the timer.

Comment: It looks like impossible use (userHasAnswered) variable, cause it will be different for different questions (some questions answered in time, some skipped). How to use timer?

Comment: @zzheads I believe you can maintain a dictionary of 'questionid : bool' to resolve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well you have to use `scheduled Timer` from class `NStimer`

the implementations are as follows:

you need to define a timer:

`var timer = Timer()//NStimer()in older versions of swift`

`timer = scheduledTimer(timeInterval: TimeInterval, invocation: NSInvocation, repeats: Bool)`

in which the `timeInterval` is the period before the execution of the required function,`invocation`is the function you want to run, and `repeats` indicates if you want the function to repeat invocation until invalidated.

you can read more about NS timers in https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/timer

I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use a array/dictionary of bool variables for this kind of problem.

You can have an array or dictionary as given in the following example.

```
var questionAnswered: [String: Bool] = ["1" : false, "2" : false, "3" : false, "4" : false, "5" : false]
```

Here, `Key = question id` and `Value = a boolean indicating whether it is answered`. You can update it depending on whether user answered the particular question or not. Then, you can use it in your code in the following way:

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(timePerQuestion)) {
   if let answered: Bool = self.questionAnswered[questionID] {
       if !answered {
          DispatchQueue.main.async {
             self.failureLabel.text = "Reseting question"
             self.failureLabel.isHidden = false
             self.quiz.skipQuestion()
             self.playNewRound()
             self.failureLabel.text = "Sorry, that's not it."
          }
       }
   }
}
```

Feel free to suggest edits to make it better :)